# Align text with div issue

Tags: html, css, flexbox, text-align

I'm trying to place the header in the animated div, but I can't figure out how.

```css
.introbox-one {
  width: 80%;
  height: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #9A00FF;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #9A00FF;
  animation: introbox-one 1s ease-in;
}

@keyframes introbox-one {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

h1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="introbox-one">
   <h1>THIS IS A HEADER</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your header is taller than the height you have set. Set it to either min-height or remove the height from the container.

Comment: Thanks for helping Andrew.